# How does this transistor radio mixer work?

Tags: transistors, radio, amplitude-modulation, mixer

I recently picked up a transistor radio, a Unitra Nova 206.  I've been studying the schematic with an interest in the AM operation for now.  Most of it makes sense and I've included an annotated snippet below.

[image]

Looking at the transistor pair T3 and T4 you can see that the RF signal arrives at the base of T3 with the LO signal applied to the emitter of both T3 and T4.  T3 seems to be producing the IF products typical of a super-het, but what about T4?

T4 has a fixed DC bias produced by detection IC UN1211/R11/R12 (about 3V at pin 2).  The LO signal gets applied to the emitter, but no RF signal.  **What then is the purpose of T4?**

More extensive schematics, etc. below.

**Full schematic (apologies for image quality!)**
[image: Full schematic (apologies for image quality!)]

http://www.elektroda.pl/rtvforum/topic1690084.html

[image]

http://www.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets_pdf/U/L/1/2/UL1211.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T4 looks like a Colpitts oscillator - it's operating as a common-base amplifier, with positive feedback to its emitter from a winding on L9/L10.

That winding also drives the emitter of T3 which is both mixer and RF amplifier with the RF input on its base.

Comment: Thanks Brian, so it's part of the LO oscillator then (along with C13 and L9)?

Comment: I haven't seen a large variety of mixers, those I have seen would have a LO coil (black adjustment screw) coupled to the emitter of a single mixer transistor.

Comment: It's drawn funny - it looks like  a push-pull pair:)

Comment: Think I understand now. That explains the third winding at T4s collector, feeding back the signal to the emitter(s).  Good stuff.

Comment: @Martin James Yes it does!:-) That threw me at first, but the more I looked at it the less sense it made.

Comment: I thought it was a long tailed pair - and in a sense it is, with one half being the oscillator and the other half the mixer/amp. There's a subtlety in that the LO is applied at both collector (via the 1st IFT) and emitter of the mixer - both in phase - but presumably different amplitudes. Quite what the collector feed  does I'm not sure, but it may improve the mixer's linearity (3rd order IP) - or they probably wouldn't do that.